# Run event handler in one permanent thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events

I have looked for solution, but found nothing.

In some class i have event

```
public class ClassWithEvent
{
    public event Action<string> SomeEvent;

    ...
}
```

and this event has subscriber

```
public class SubscriberClass
{
    public void SomeMethod(string value)
    {
        ...
    }
}

ClassWithEvent objectWithEvent = new ClassWithEvent();

SubscriberClass subscriberObject = new SubscriberClass();

objectWithEvent.SomeEvent += subscriberObject.SomeMethod;
```

Somewhere in main thread this event can be invoked.

```
if(SomeEvent != null)
    SomeEvent(someString);
```

And when it is happened its handler has to run in second thread. But every time in the same thread, so this second thread has to be permanent and not be terminated after first execution.

Help me please to implement this.

Answer (score 7):

Create a shared queue:

```
private BlockingCollection<string> queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();
```

Create your dedicated thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(HandleEvents);
thread.Start();
```

Process events on that thread:

```
private void HandleEvents()
{
    foreach (string someValue in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) 
    { 
        //Do stuff 
    }
}
```

Place items into the queue when the event is raised:

```
objectWithEvent.SomeEvent += (x) => queue.Add(x);
```

On shutdown complete the queue:

```
queue.CompleteAdding();
```

Comment: Instead of a `while` loop a much easier way is `foreach (string someValue in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) { //Do stuff }`. It behaves the same as your version except `Take()` has the opportunity for a race condition in multi consumer environments where it could get called on a collection that was already complete. `Take()` throws a exception, `GetConsumingEnumerable()` just exits the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Agreed.

Answer (score -1):

Well it's quite tricky but it should work.

You will need to create the permanent thread, for example by starting while(true) there, and a List of actions, which will be checked inside of this loop, something like this:

```
ConcurrentBag<Action> actions = new ConcurrentBag<Action>();
new Thread(
delegate()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Action a;
        if (actions.TryTake(out a))
           a();
    }
}
).Start();
```

And every time you want to rise the event just add the action to the List:

```
actions.Add(new Action(() => { SomeEvent("abc"); }));
```

Comment: Ok my dear downvoters, I just tried to show a way to go, but here is the thread safe version with the code for adding to the Bag.

Comment: @VladL This code will continuously burn CPU cycles spinning in that while loop if the bag is empty.  If the bag is not empty you're going to execute the same `Action` repeatedly since you never remove from the bag.

Comment: @Zer0 TryPeek is similar to Stack's Pop(). It will remove the item from the bag if there is one

Comment: @VladL [No, it won't.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394862(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Zer0 damn you are right, I've mixed it up with TryTake. Thanks